# highcharts tilemap logarithmic colorAxis fails when 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to implement a tilemap in highcharts with a logarithmic colorAxis, however, I keep getting highcharts error #10 (can't plot zero or subzero values on a logarithmic axis).

Can i somehow get around this error? There is almost nothing about this error in docs.

My colorAxis now look like this:

```
"colorAxis": {
    "min": 4849377.1,
    "max": 160000000.3,
    "type": 'logarithmic',
    "minColor": '#EEEEFF',
    "maxColor": '#000022',
    "stops": [
      [0, '#A9A9FF'],
      [0.5, '#4444FF'],
      [1, '#000022']
    ]
},
```